# Java caching network files

Tags: java, caching

I'm working on this program that needs to download files from a network. The same file is downloaded many times, so we need to cache them to the local file system. Is there a java library that, given a cache directory, will manage the cache and the downloading of the resources?

The library needs to have some kind of open source license.

Thank you.

Comment: what's the transport?  Could you use squid as part of the project?

Answer (score 0):

URLConnection supports caching, but there is no default cache implementation. See this article for more info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-cache.html

If you plug in your own cache implementation, you can just use a regular URLConnection to download the item, and your cache will be used.

Answer (score 0):

though [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html) is not an open source, but its free version is available, which can serve the purpose for you. once you create the local cache, you can download the files from there.